# Count and Sort On Array Intersection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this schema

```
module.exports = function(conn, mongoose) {
// var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');


var UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        first_name: String,
        last_name:String,
        sex: String,
        fk_hobbies: []


    }
    , {
        timestamps: true
    }, {collection: 'wt_users'});




  return conn.model('wt_users', UsersSchema);
};
```

And for example I have these users in data base

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5aca2ac25c1d8adeb4a2dab0"),
     first_name:"Pierro",
     last_name:"pierre",
     sex:"H",
     fk_hobbies: [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1f8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Art"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c8d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Sport"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d9c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Fete"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5acaf84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Série"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("6ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Jeux vidéo"
            }
      ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9fa075c1d8adeb4a2da99"),
    first_name:"jean",
    last_name:"mark",
    sex:"H",
    fk_hobbies: [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Musique"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f24d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Chiller"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84c5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Papoter"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d2c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Manger"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Film"
            }
       ]
   },
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aca0a635c1d8adeb4a2da9d"),
        first_name:"michael",
        last_name:"ferrari",
        sex:"H",
        fk_hobbies: [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2ea97"),
                "name" : "fashion"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1e8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Voyage"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84c5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Papoter"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d2c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Manger"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Film"
            }
      ]
},
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9fa074c1d8adeb4a2da99"),
    first_name:"Philip",
     last_name:"roi",
     sex:"H",
     fk_hobbies: 
    [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac7f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Musique"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f24d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Chiller"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84c5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Papoter"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d2c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Manger"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"),
                "name" : "Film"
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to create a mongoose query that match user getted by id, with others users in database according this :
the query will return firstly the users that have the max number of the same hobbies, that is 5, then the users that have the same 4 hobbies ...

I create a solution fully Javascipt / node js, Is there any query with mongo ?
this is my solution

```
//var user : the current user that search other similar users : jean mark : 5ac9fa075c1d8adeb4a2da99
//var users : all other users
 var tab = []


                async.each(users, function(item, next1){
                    var j = 0;
                    var hobbies = item["fk_hobbies"]


                    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        var index = hobbies.findIndex(x => x["_id"] == user[0]["fk_hobbies"][i]["_id"].toString());




                        if(index != -1)
                            j++
                    }

                    if(j != 0)
                        tab.push({nbHob:j, user:item})

                    next1()
                }, function ()
                {
                   var tab2 = tab.sort(compare)
                res.json({success:true, data:tab2})
            })


function compare(a,b) {
    if (a.nbHob > b.nbHob)
        return -1;
    if (a.nbHob < b.nbHob)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

the displayed result is like this
nbHob : represents the number of similar hobbies

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"nbHob":5,"user":{"_id":"5ac9fa074c1d8adeb4a2da99","u_first_name":"Akram","u_last_name":"Cherif","u_email":"","u_login":"","u_password":"","u_user_type":0,"u_date_of_birth":"","u_civility":0,"u_sex":"H","u_phone_number":"","u_facebook_id":"","u_google_id":"","u_twitter_id":"","u_profile_image":"","u_about":"","u_profession":"","u_fk_additional_infos":[null],"u_budget":0,"u_address":{"country":"France","state":"Paris","city":"TM","zip":76001},"u_fk_hobbies":[{"name":"Musique","_id":"5ac7f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Chiller","_id":"5ac9f24d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Papoter","_id":"5ac9f84c5c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Manger","_id":"5ac9f84d2c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Film","_id":"5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"}]}},{"nbHob":3,"user":{"_id":"5aca0a635c1d8adeb4a2da9d","u_first_name":"Chawki","u_last_name":"Gasmi","u_email":"","u_login":"","u_password":"","u_user_type":0,"u_date_of_birth":"","u_civility":0,"u_sex":"H","u_phone_number":"","u_facebook_id":"","u_google_id":"","u_twitter_id":"","u_profile_image":"","u_about":"","u_profession":"","u_fk_additional_infos":[null],"u_budget":{"min":500,"max":850},"u_address":{"country":"","state":"","city":"","zip":0},"u_fk_hobbies":[{"name":"fashion","_id":"5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2ea97"},{"name":"Voyage","_id":"5ac9f84d5c1e8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Papoter","_id":"5ac9f84c5c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Manger","_id":"5ac9f84d2c1d8adeb4a2da97"},{"name":"Film","_id":"5ac9f84d5c1d8adeb4a2da97"}]}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question data seems a bit messed up due to probably far to liberal copy/paste since every hobby has the same `ObjectId` value. But I can correct that with a full self contained example:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/people';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const hobbySchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  sex: String,
  fk_hobbies: [hobbySchema]
});

const Hobby = mongoose.model('Hobby', hobbySchema)
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const userData = [
  {
    "first_name" : "Pierro",
    "last_name" : "pierre",
    "sex" : "H",
    "fk_hobbies" : [ 
       "Art",  "Sport",  "Fete", "Série", "Jeux vidéo"
    ]
  },
  {
   "first_name": "jean",
   "last_name" : "mark",
    "sex" : "H",
    "fk_hobbies" : [
      "Musique", "Chiller", "Papoter", "Manger", "Film"
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name" : "michael",
    "last_name" : "ferrari",
    "sex" : "H",
    "fk_hobbies" : [ 
      "fashion", "Voyage", "Papoter", "Manger", "Film"
    ]
  },
  {
    "first_name" : "Philip",
    "last_name" : "roi",
    "sex" : "H",
    "fk_hobbies" : [ 
      "Musique", "Chiller", "Papoter", "Manger", "Film"
    ]
  }
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);
    
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove())
    );

    const hobbies = await Hobby.insertMany(
      [
        ...userData
          .reduce((o, u) => [ ...o, ...u.fk_hobbies ], [])
          .reduce((o, u) => o.set(u,1) , new Map())
      ]
      .map(([name,v]) => ({ name }))
    );

    const users = await User.insertMany(userData.map(u => 
      ({ 
        ...u, 
        fk_hobbies: u.fk_hobbies.map(f => hobbies.find(h => f === h.name))
      })
    ));

    let user = await User.findOne({
      "first_name" : "Philip",
      "last_name" : "roi"      
    });
    let user_hobbies = user.fk_hobbies.map(h => h._id );

    let result = await User.aggregate([
      { "$match": {
        "_id": { "$ne": user._id },
        "fk_hobbies._id": { "$in": user_hobbies }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "numHobbies": {
          "$size": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$fk_hobbies._id",
              user_hobbies
            ]
          }
        },
        "fk_hobbies": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$fk_hobbies",
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$this",
                {
                  "shared": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$in": [ "$$this._id", user_hobbies ] },
                      "then": true,
                      "else": "$$REMOVE"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "numHobbies": -1 } }
    ]);

    log(result);

    mongoose.disconnect();
    
  } catch(e) {

  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
})()
```

Most of that is just "setup" to re-create the data set, but simply put we're just adding the users and their hobbies and keeping a "unique" identifier for each "unique hobby" by name. This is probably what you actually meant in the question, and it's the sort of model you should be following.

The interesting part is all in the `.aggregate()` statement, which is how we "query" then "count" the matching hobbies and enable the "server" to sort the results before returning to the client.

Given a current user ( and the last one in the list you included has the most interesting matches ), we then focus on this section of the code:

```
    // Simulates getting the current user to compare against
    let user = await User.findOne({
      "first_name" : "Philip",
      "last_name" : "roi"      
    });

    // Just get the list of _id values from the current user for reference
    let user_hobbies = user.fk_hobbies.map(h => h._id );

    let result = await User.aggregate([
      // Find all users not the current user with at least one of the hobbies
      { "$match": {
        "_id": { "$ne": user._id },
        "fk_hobbies._id": { "$in": user_hobbies }
      }},
      // Add the count of matches, "optionally" we are marking the matched
      // hobbies in the array as well.
      { "$addFields": {
        "numHobbies": {
          "$size": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$fk_hobbies._id",
              user_hobbies
            ]
          }
        },
        "fk_hobbies": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$fk_hobbies",
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$this",
                {
                  "shared": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$in": [ "$$this._id", user_hobbies ] },
                      "then": true,
                      "else": "$$REMOVE"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      // Sort the results by the "most" hobbies, which is "descending" order
      { "$sort": { "numHobbies": -1 } }
    ]);
```

I've commented those steps for you but let's expand on that.

Firstly we presume you have the current user already returned from the database by whatever means you have already done. For the purposes of the rest of the operations, all your really need from that user is the `_id` of the "User" itself and of course the `_id` values from each of that user's chosen hobbies. We can do a quick [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operation as it shown here, but we keep a copy for ease of reference and not repeating that through the remaining code.

Then we get to the actual aggregate statement. The first condition there is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), this works like a standard query expression with all the same operators. We want two things from these query conditions:

- Get all users **except** the current user for consideration;
- AND where those users contain at least one match on the same hobbies, by `_id` value.

So the condition for "everyone else" is essentially to supply the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) "not equal to" operator in argument to the `_id` value, comparing of course to the current user `_id`. The second condition to get only those with the same hobbies uses the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator against the `_id` field of the `fk_hobbies` array. In MongoDB query parlance we denote this as `"$fk_hobbies._id"` in order to match against the "inner" `_id` property values.

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator itself takes a "list" as it's argument and compares each value in the list supplied to the property the condition is assigned to. MongoDB itself does not care that `fk_hobbies` is an array or a single value, and will simply look for an match for anything in the provided list. Think of [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) as a short way of writing [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), except you don't need to explicitly include the same property name on every condition.

Now you have the correct documents selected and have discarded any users who do not share any of the same hobbies we can move on to the next stage. Note also that the whole [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) considers it logical that you only want those "matching" users. If you actually wanted to see "all users" including those with "no matches", then you can simply omit the whole [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage. Your code is discarding anything that was not counted, so this code simply doesn't bother to count anything which "must" have a `0` count.

The [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage pipeline stage is a quick way to "add new fields" to the document returned in results. The main output you want here is the `"numHobbies"` in addition to the other user details, so this pipeline stage operator is the optimal way to do this, but if you're MongoDB server is a bit older then you can simply specify "all" fields you want to include in addition to any new ones using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead.

In order to "count" the number of hobbies in common we essentially use two aggregation operators, which are [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/). Both of these should be available in an MongoDB version you really should be using in production.

In respective order the [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator "compares sets" which is in this case the list of `_id` values within `fk_hobbies`, both from the current selected user we stored earlier and from the present document being considered in the expression. The result from this operator is the list of values which are the "same" between both lists.

Naturally the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator looks at the returned list ( or set ) from [`$setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) and returns the number of entries in that list. This of course is the "matched count".

The next part involves projecting a "re-written" form of the `fk_hobbies` array. This is totally optional and by my own design for demonstration purposes. *"If"* you wanted to do what I am doing here as well, then what this bit of code does is adds an additional property to the objects of the `fk_hobbies` array to indicate where that particular hobby was one of those which matched the list.

I'm saying this is "optional" because I'm actually demonstrating two features available for MongoDB 3.6 **only**. These involve the usage of [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) on the inner array elements and the usage of [Conditionally Exlcuding Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields).

Stepping through that, since `fk_hobbies` is an array we need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator in order to "reshape" the objects inside it. This operator allows us to process each array member and return a new value based on the transformations we include as it's argument. It's usage is much the same as [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for JavaScript or any other language which implements a similar operation.

Therefore for each object in the array ( `$$this` ) we apply the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator which will "merge" the result of it's arguments. These are provided as the `$$this` for the current object as it already is, and the second argument in the expression which is doing something new and interesting.

Here we use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator, which is a "ternary" operator ( or `if..then..else` expression ) which considers a condition `if` and then returns either the `then` argument where that expression was true, or the `else` expression where it was false. The expression here is another form of [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) used as an aggregation expression. In this form the first argument is a singular value `$$this._id` which will be compared to a list expression in the second argument. That second argument is of course the list of the current user hobby id's we kept earlier, and are using again for comparison.

That usage of [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) alone would return either `true` or `false` where it was a match. But the extra demonstrated action here is that within the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) expresion, our `else` condition for `false` returns the new and special `$$REMOVE` value. What this means is that with our `"shared"` property we are adding to each object in the array, rather than assigning it a value of `false` where there was no match, we actually don't include that property in the output document at all.

That "optional" part is really just there as a "nice touch" to indicate which "hobbies" were matched in the conditions, rather than simply returning the count. If you like it then use it, and if you don't have MongoDB 3.6 with those features you can simply do that same alteration in the returned documents from the aggregation output anyway:

```
    let result = await User.aggregate([
      { "$match": {
        "_id": { "$ne": user._id },
        "fk_hobbies._id": { "$in": user_hobbies }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "numHobbies": {
          "$size": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$fk_hobbies._id",
              user_hobbies
            ]
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "numHobbies": -1 } }
    ]);

    // map each result after return
    result = result.map(r => 
      ({
        ...r,
        fk_hobbies: r.fk_hobbies.map(h =>
          ({
            ...h,
            ...(( user_hobbies.map(i => i.toString() ).indexOf( h._id.toString() ) != -1 )
                ? { "shared": true } : {} )
          })
        )
      })
    )
```

Either way, the main thing you wanted out of any [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) statement was the actual `"numHobbies"` value indicating the count. And the main reason we did that on the server was so that we can also [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on the server, which would in turn allow you to add things like [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) to larger result sets for purposes of paging where it simply would not be practical to get all the results from the collection, even if they were filtered in the initial match or regular query.

Anyhow, from the small sample of documents in the question as also generated in the sample listing, we get a result like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed8a",
    "first_name": "jean",
    "last_name": "mark",
    "sex": "H",
    "fk_hobbies": [
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed7d",
        "name": "Musique",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed7e",
        "name": "Chiller",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed7f",
        "name": "Papoter",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed80",
        "name": "Manger",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed81",
        "name": "Film",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "numHobbies": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed90",
    "first_name": "michael",
    "last_name": "ferrari",
    "sex": "H",
    "fk_hobbies": [
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed82",
        "name": "fashion",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed83",
        "name": "Voyage",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed7f",
        "name": "Papoter",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed80",
        "name": "Manger",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "5ad6bbe63365bc3428feed81",
        "name": "Film",
        "__v": 0,
        "shared": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "numHobbies": 3
  }
]
```

So there are two users that were returned and we counted the matching hobbies as `5` and `3` respectively and returned the one with the most matched first. You can also see the addition of the `"shared"` property on each of the matched hobbies to indicate which of the hobbies in each of the returned users lists were also shared with the original user they were compared with.

---

> **NOTE**: You were probably just "trying things" but your usage of `async.each()` in your question was not really necessary since none of the inner code is actually "async" itself. Even in the listing here, the only thing you actually need to "await" as an async call after you have the current user to compare is the `.aggregate()` response itself.
>
> So if at any part of this you were presuming you would be "awaiting requests within a loop", then you were mistaken. Simply ask the database for the results and await their return.
>
> One request to the database is all that is required.
>
> *N.B* It's also 2018, so you really should start to understand Promises and usage of `async/await` with them. The code is much cleaner that way and surely any newly developed application should be running in an environment with this support. So "callback helper" libraries like "node async", are a little "old hat" and outmoded in a modern context.